# Apply a function for each pair of vector elements in R

Tags: r, apply

I have a data frame of elements imported from mongo database, sample:

```
#      | Mcg    | Gvh    | Alm    | Mit    | Vac    | Nuc
:----: | :----: | :----: | :----: | :----: | :----: | :----:
1      | 0.62   | 0.42   | 0.47   | 0.16   | 0.52   | 0.22
2      | 0.60   | 0.40   | 0.52   | 0.46   | 0.53   | 0.22
3      | 0.47   | 0.32   | 0.64   | 0.30   | 0.63   | 0.22
4      | 0.46   | 0.39   | 0.54   | 0.22   | 0.48   | 0.25
5      | 0.50   | 0.46   | 0.52   | 0.16   | 0.52   | 0.26

data = data.frame(
   Mcg = c(0.62, 0.60, 0.47, 0.46, 0.50),
   Gvh = c(0.42, 0.40, 0.32, 0.39, 0.46),
   Alm = c(0.47, 0.52, 0.64, 0.54, 0.52),
   Mit = c(0.16, 0.46, 0.30, 0.22, 0.16),
   Vac = c(0.52, 0.53, 0.63, 0.48, 0.52),
   Nuc = c(0.22, 0.22, 0.22, 0.25, 0.26),
   row.names = c(1:5)
)
```

I need to compute number of shared nearest neighbors for each pair of examples based on distance matrix and if the value is above given threshold save those examples indexes in a list named clusters.

```
#      | 1      | 2      | 3      | 4      | 5
:----: | :----: | :----: | :----: | :----: | :----:
1      | 0.00   | 0.31   | 0.31   | 0.19   | 0.14
2      | 0.31   | 0.00   | 0.27   | 0.28   | 0.32
3      | 0.31   | 0.27   | 0.00   | 0.21   | 0.26
4      | 0.19   | 0.28   | 0.21   | 0.00   | 0.11
5      | 0.14   | 0.32   | 0.26   | 0.11   | 0.00

dists = as.matrix(
   dist(data, method = "euclidean", diag = FALSE, upper = FALSE, p = 2)
)
```

I already have a working code with 'for' loops:

```
# get indexes of k nearest neighbors
Neighbors <- function(id, k) {
   as.integer( names( sort( dists[id, -id] )[1:k] ) )
}

threshold = 5
k = 10
clusters = vector("list", (k - threshold))

for (y in 1:(nrow(data) - 1)) {

   neighbors.e1 = Neighbors(y, k)

   for (z in (y+1):(nrow(data))) {

      neighbors.e2 = Neighbors(z, k)
      snn = sum(table(c(neighbors.e1, neighbors.e2)) == 2)

      if (snn > threshold) {
         cluster.id = snn - threshold
         if (!(y %in% clusters[[cluster.id]])) {
            clusters[[cluster.id]] = c(clusters[[cluster.id]], y)
         }
         if (!(z %in% clusters[[cluster.id]])) {
            clusters[[cluster.id]] = c(clusters[[cluster.id]], z)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This solution is really slow. Therefore I want to optimize it by using apply function instead of loops.

Here is a 'clusters' list for a complete dataset (1484 rows)

```
> clusters
[[1]]
 [1]  1  3  6  7 19  2 23  8 16 17 18 20  4  5 14 21 24 15  9 10 12 22 11 13

[[2]]
 [1]  1 17 24  2  3  7  8 16 18 20  6  4 10 12 13 22  5 19 21 23  9 15 11 14

[[3]]
 [1]  4 11  7 16 19  8 18 10 12 13 14 22 20 17 24

[[4]]
[1]  5 21  7  8 18 20

[[5]]
NULL
```

Comment: The code generates a emtpy list with 5 slots for `clusters`variable. Its correct?

Comment: @gonzalez.ivan90 for given data samples (5 rows) it is very likely that the clusters will be empty, my database contains 1484 rows, as result each list in clusters contains a dozen or so rows indexes. I shall edit the question providing my clusters result.

Comment: Ok. I'm trying to reproduce your result in order to find and equal answer with a faster method. Can you share your data? Or give a example data that can generate a reproducible and traceable result?

Comment: @gonzalez.ivan90 sure, complete dataset: [link](https://pastebin.com/2mFUD3rg)